# Update a state that depends on another state provided by a hook

Tags: reactjs

I have a code similar to below:

```
const Example = (props) => {
    //custom hook that returns a country name selected by user
    { selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry } = useSelectedCountry(); 
    const [country, setCountry] = useState();
    const countryList = props.countryList;

    return(
        <Box>
            <label htmlFor='country'>Country</label>
                <Select 
                    sx={{ m: 1, width: inputSelectWidth, mt: 3, height: 35, ml: 12 }}
                    value={country}
                    onChange={(e) => { setCountry(e.target.value); } }
                >
                    {
                         countryList.map(country => {
                         return (
                             <MenuItem 
                                  value={country.countryName}
                                  key={country.countryID}
                             >
                                  {country.countryName}
                             </MenuItem>
                         );
                         })
                    }
                </Select>
        </Box>
    );

}
export default Example;
```

I need the `country` to change when `selectedCountry` is changes. But `selectedCountry` is updated in another component. If I `console.log(selectedCountry);` in this component it gets updated every time I select different country from the other component.
Although `country` should change when `selectedCountry` changes, `country` can have its own value. For example

```
selectedCountry: A, country: A
selectedCountry: B, country: B
selectedCountry: B, country: C
selectedCountry: B, country: D
```

I tried `value={selectedCountry}` But then value of `country` and `selectedCountry` are always same. I need to implement the above scenario. 
I don't know how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: When selectedCountry = A and country = A, then selectedCountry change to B, country change to B or still is A?

Comment: country changes to B, for the first two cases country takes the value from selectedCountry, in the last two cases country has its own value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `React.useEffect` hooks to set up the behaviour you need.  The code may look something like that inside your `Example` component:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  // This function will be executed each time the `country` is changed
  // like in the `Select` component.
}, [country]};

React.useEffect(() => {
  // This function will be executed each time the `selectedCountry` is
  // changed, probably outside the `Example` component.
}, [selectedCountry]};

React.useEffect(() => {
  // This function will be executed each time either `country`
  // or `selectedCountry` is changed.
}, [country, selectedCountry]};
```

Use whatever option you find the best and put the required logic inside the function.  And don't forget to import `React` or the `useEffect` hook in the beginning of the file.

More on this and other hooks on React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html.